# Algorithm to distribute a set of random integers from input file to N output (bucket) files

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to improve my algorithm which distributes input data from a single input file to N output files. The input data is distributed in the following way:

If for example the input file contains values 5 2 4 6 3 1 0 8 5 9 and I have N = 4 output files, the values are distributed like:

- file_0: 2 1 0
- file_1: 5 4 3 5
- file_2: 6 8
- file_3: 9

So every value should be "mapped" to appropriate file in the range [0, N-1]. Each of this files will be later sorted and as you can see their concatenation will produce the sorted sequence of the input values.

All output file paths are stored in a File array called bucket_files and what am I trying to do here is to have some kind of a hash function H(input_value) that maps the input_value to array index in the range [0, N-1].

What I have so far is

```
private static void distributeData(int N, File main_string_file) {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 9;
    long left_interval_border;
    long right_interval_border;

    int input_buff_size = 8;
    File bucket_files[] = new File[N];
    int input_buffer[] = new int[input_buff_size / 2];
    BufferedWriter bucket_file_writers[] = new BufferedWriter[N];
    BufferedReader main_file_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(main_string_file));

    left_interval_border = min;
    long range = (int) Math.ceil(max / N);
    right_interval_border = range;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        bucket_files[i] = new File("/path/to/files/file_" + i + ".txt");
        bucket_file_writers[i] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bucket_files[i], true));
    }

    try {
        while (main_file_reader.ready()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input_buffer.length; i++) {
                input_buffer[i] = Integer.parseInt(main_file_reader.readLine());
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < input_buffer.length; j++) {
                    if (input_buffer[j] >= left_interval_border && input_buffer[j] <= right_interval_border) {
                        bucket_file_writers[i - 1].write(Integer.toString(input_buffer[j]));
                        bucket_file_writers[i - 1].write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                }

                left_interval_border = right_interval_border + 1;
                right_interval_border = left_interval_border + range;
            }

            left_interval_border = min;
            right_interval_border = range;
        }
    }

    catch (EOFException eofe) {
        System.out.println("Reached end of file!");
    }
}
```

This approach is the first I came up with, it is very slow and will not work good if the input file would be much bigger and any kind of a better solution is more than welcome :) That double for loop is a bottle neck which I want to change into something much better and faster.

Thanks!

Notes

- all the files are .txt files and every value is separated with a new line
- N is at least 2 and up to a reasonable number, let's say 200 max
- main_string_file will be much bigger and will contain random values in a range from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE-1
- min and max are set in advance (0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) that means there is no special search for actual min and max in a file

Comment: Instead of reading all the data first, I suggest writing out the values as you read them. You can calculate which file to write to instead of iterating over them. I suggest writing to a PrintWriter.println(x);

Comment: So u suggest to remove that input_buffer loop? Why is PrintWriter.println(x) better? You are right, I need to calculate the index, the question is how, that is what I am asking here.

Comment: Should distribution be random? Is it okay of any value goes into any of 4 files?

Comment: yes, println is a one liner much simpler, I would use division, see my answer

Comment: @Anand Undavia: no, distribution should be like I wrote in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use println and a calculate which file to write to.

```
PrintWriter printWriters[] = new PrintWriter[N];
int range = (int) ((max + N - 1) / N);

for (int i = 0; i < printWriters.length; i++) 
    printWriters[i] = new PrintWriter("/path/to/files/file_" + i + ".txt");

for (String line; (line = main_file_reader.readLine()) != null; )
    printWriter[Integer.parseInt(line) / range].println(line);

for (int i = 0; i < printWriters.length; i++) 
    printWriter[i].close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Peter Lawrey. Are you sure this is correct? If you take the first value(5) and divide it by range=2 in this case, you will get index 2, but the correct one would be 1. Any comments on this?

Thanks

Comment: If you use `long range = (max + N) / N;`, as long as `min` is 0, in the above code you will get the answer you are looking for. If `min` could be non-zero you need `long range = ((max-min) + N) / N;` and also `printWriter[(Integer.parseInt(line)-min) / range].println(line);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the way you say you want the buckets broken down, your bucket size is computed by `range/(numBuckets-1)`. Except in the case where the range is evenly divided by the number of buckets. So what you have is:

```
int bucketSize;
if (range % bucketSize == 0)
    bucketSize = range / numBuckets;
else
    bucketSize = range / (numBuckets-1);
```

That's a one-time computation once you know the number of buckets and the range of items.

Then, you can compute the bucket for each item with a simple division. If the item is `i`, then:

```
int bucket = i/bucketSize;
```